# Jupyter notebook: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently installed jupyter notebooks on my macbook pro.
When I create a new notebook, I see the following exception coming continuously on the terminal where I started the notebook.

```
Monideeps-MacBook-Pro:PythonNotebooks monideepde$ jupyter-notebook 
[I 12:18:43.675 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/monideepde/Documents/PythonNotebooks
[I 12:18:43.675 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 12:18:43.676 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 12:18:43.676 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=dcb1990694d91ded77f4287a588886ea567b5907ac8aeafa
[I 12:18:43.676 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:18:43.677 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=dcb1990694d91ded77f4287a588886ea567b5907ac8aeafa
[I 12:18:43.896 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 12:18:44.778 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/moment/locale/en-gb.js?v=20180104121843 (::1) 21.10ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[I 12:18:54.840 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 12:18:55.716 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/moment/locale/en-gb.js?v=20180104121843 (::1) 3.06ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[I 12:18:55.920 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5e16fa4b-3e35-4265-89b0-ab36bb0573f5
[W 12:18:55.941 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20180104121843 (::1) 5.57ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[I 12:18:56.998 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 5e16fa4b-3e35-4265-89b0-ab36bb0573f5
[E 12:18:57.001 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/5e16fa4b-3e35-4265-89b0-ab36bb0573f5/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-5.0a1-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg/tornado/websocket.py", line 494, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook-5.2.2-py2.7.egg/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 258, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook-5.2.2-py2.7.egg/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 168, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[I 12:18:58.021 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 5e16fa4b-3e35-4265-89b0-ab36bb0573f5
```

Python version is 2.7.

Any pointers to how I can resolve this?

Comment: I modified the file "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook-5.2.2-py2.7.egg/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py" to remove the io_loop argument and it is working ok now. But that seems to be a hack rather than a fix. Please let me know if some one knows a proper fix to the issue.

Comment: This is a bug in Jupyter that has been fixed in development. Tornado deprecated the io_loop argument, so the "fix" really is just remove it until Jupyter releases a new version

Comment: Or downgrade tornado<5 https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3568

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I modified the file "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook-5.2.2-py2.7.egg/‌​notebook/base/zmqhan‌​dlers.py" to remove the `io_loop` argument.

Based on bkanuka's comment, this is the way to go until Jupyter releases a new version.

Comment: Linux user here: You can find that file with `locate zmqhan‌​dlers.py` on your machine. I had the same problem and the same solution.

Answer (score 54):

Downgrade tornado, this worked for me.

`pip install tornado==4.5.3`

based on: https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne/issues/689

Comment: i've updated all the packages then i got this error. The only solution that works for me is this answer. Ty.

Comment: I prefer not to modify the code, as the accepted answer suggested. Downgrading worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I upgraded all the jupyter related package but doesn't work. This downgrade solution helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

It is a version incompatibility issue. Upgrading Jupyter solves it. Here is what you should try in macOS:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

Comment: This worked for me , I was short on memory so I did not create different environments for different thing and if finally ended up breaking some code because of the upgrades and the down grades

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this error after updating the ipykernel module.

After upgrading the jupyter module it started without errors. On Ubuntu I ran the following to update jupyter:

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

Or for Python3

```
sudo -H pip3 install jupyter
```

Comment: pip3 would update python 3, wouldn't it? Or does it work with python 2 as well since that was what the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess I'm not used to anything else than Python3 anymore. I'll correct it,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue post Apache Airflow installation; Airflow requires  constraint file, I suspect there were conflicts.

Following a [Jupyter Github Discussion Thread](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/369) someone provided a solution to upgrade jupyterlab.

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab jupyterlab_server jupyter_server
```

This remedied the error.