# GraphLab Create sFrame.show() function error when executing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I've installed GraphLab Create using Anaconda. Everything seems to be fine with SFrames, I can manipulate data and ingest it but I can't execute the function `show()`. The error message is like this:

```
Error: Requested port is unavailable
inspect.pyc in find_vars(var)
     42     (variable_name, variable) = _find_variable_name(var)
     43     if variable_name is not None:
---> 44         target.add_variable((variable_name,), variable)
     45     return variable_name
     46 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_variable'
```

Also, I tried to instead change the target of the canvas to the notebook itself cause the port thing might have caused the problem, but the error when I execute `graphlab.canvas.set_target('ipynb')` is this:

```
util.pyc in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    310         # singleton magic.  If we get rid of that we can switch to __init__
    311         # here too.
--> 312         instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
    313         return instance
    314 

TypeError: initialize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
```

Here's the specs of my environment:

```
Python: 2.7
OS: Windows 10
Jupyter Notebook: 5.4.1
Anaconda: 4.3.30
GraphLab: 2.1
```

EDIT: Added the error message on top of the stack trace which is `Error: Requested port is unavailable`

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade tornado.

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

Find more answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090119/jupyter-notebook-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-io-l)

Answer (score 0):

I used Anaconda3 5.1.0 and got a problem similar to yours.
Then, I uninsatll it, and download GraphLabCreateLauncher from [Turi](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html). Run the launcher and install **Anaconda2 4.0.0.** Now, the problem is solved. I hope it will help you.